# Probabilistic model of a coin toss: Impossible events in the event set

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

Consider the experiment where a fair coin is tossed three times. The sample space is $\Omega = \{TTT, TTH, \ldots, HHT, HHH\}$ the set of all possible combinations of heads and tails resulting from three tosses. I was asked to give a probabilistic model using this sample space. What confuses me is finding a well-defined set of possible events. I understand that any family of events $\mathcal{A}$ in a probabilistic model must satisfy:

- $A \in \mathcal{A} \implies A^{c} \in \mathcal{A}$
- $A_1 \in \mathcal{A}, A_2 \in \mathcal{A}, \ldots  \implies \left(\bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1} A_{i}\right) \in \mathcal{A}$

It is natural then to take $\mathcal{A} := \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. However, in this set there are many events that cannot happen in our experiment - for instance, $\{\{TTT, TTH\}\}$ or $\emptyset$. In general, only those $A \in \mathcal{A}$ satisfying $|A| = 1$ are possible in our experiment. Is it correct to still use this definition of $\mathcal{A}$ and define

$$
P(A) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{8} & |A| = 1 \\ 0 & otherwise \end{cases}
$$

or should I redefine $\mathcal{A}$? It seems that using this definition makes $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ a well-defined probabilistic model, but I find it very counter-intuitive to consider in $\mathcal{A}$ events that cannot occur in our experiment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is based on a small misunderstanding of events.

First, the event $\{TTT, TTH\}$ is not impossible. It is the event that occurs if one of the outcomes $TTT$ or $TTH$ does. Thus it has two ways of occurring.

Second, there is nothing wrong with some event being impossible. In particular, the empty event $\varnothing$ is impossible. It is just that it is always going to be assigned probability zero, i.e. $P(\varnothing) = 0$. Conceptually, events are simply the objects in the model that are capable of having a probability.

Thus in this case, you can safely take the set of events, often known as the *algebra*, to be the set of subsets of the sample space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very clear.